# Cloning from GitHub

Tags: github, npm, yarnpkg

I have currently made a repository on GitHub and I am using react redux to make a small app example.

I have installed the necessary requirements that it works for me, but if I clone my app, I get a warning, `react-scripts: command not found`. I am a little confused at what I have done wrong. Surely if I installed yarn into my project, shouldn't it be available for someone to immediately look at it using `yarn start`?

Comment: Have you run `yarn install` in the new clone? If you've followed sensible practices `node_modules` isn't in the repo so you need to get the dependencies again.

Comment: I did. But my issue is, and maybe it is not possible, that someone that already has everything already installed should be able to use my clone without having to instal yarn again. I was working with my group yesterday and it was a problem that I was hoping to solve!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have set up a git ignore for my node modules, as requested by my teacher. He said that that if i didn't that was frowned upon in the github community! I'm just a bit confused.

Comment: That would be possible if you didn't ignore the dependencies, but then you run into problems with any that use platform-specific binaries and your git repo would contain a huge number of files. Reinstalling is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I feel that maybe my teacher has given me conflicting requirements. last week, got told to make sure my  node_modules were not included when I upload to github, this week, make sure he can open my project and yarn start immediately!

Comment: You could write a `prestart` script in your package file that always ran an install before starting I suppose, but that seems a bit unnecessary. Maybe better to clarify the requirements with your teacher.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your node_modules folder is in .gitignore file then you have to re-install the dependencies.

After cloning the repository,make sure to enter into the cloned directory using:-

```
cd cloned-directory
```

And then run:-

```
yarn
```

And then run:-

```
yarn start
```